# Finding the angle of a line in 3D space projected onto a 2D plane

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

I'm actually a programmer here. I have a math problem, but I don't major in math so I may not explain this clearly.

I have a line in a 3D space with points A and B (e.g. (3,4,8) to (6,9,2)). I (or my eyes) am at point C looking towards a direction that allows me to see point A, as well as part of the line or the whole line.

If whatever I'm seeing is being projected onto a 2D plane, how do I calculate the angle between the line and the top of the 2D plane?

Comment: Umm.... where is $C$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Another way to explain this is that there is a camera at Point C, and the camera is facing a particular direction (heading), tilted at certain angle (roll), vertically pointing at certain angle (pitch). A photo is taken (with the line within it), which projects the 3D space into a 2D plane. I'm trying to calculate the angle of the line in the photo.

Comment: Just set the $z$ coordinates to $0$.  But you're *very* unclear as to the location of $C$... and that is confusing you and everyone.  "A particular direction" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have sufficient information.

What you need to know is

- The 3D direction vector $\vec{w}$ perpendicular to the viewing plane: from $C$ into the 3D direction that passes through the center of the 2D viewing plane.  This is the direction you are viewing at.
- The 3D direction vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ corresponding to "right" and "up", both perpendicular to $\vec{w}$.  Often only one of them is specified, because the other can be obtained from the other two via vector cross product: $\vec{v} = \vec{w} \times \vec{u}$ and $\vec{u} = \vec{v} \times \vec{w}$.

Since their lengths are irrelevant, they are usually unit vectors.  The following assumes so, that $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert = \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \lVert\vec{w}\rVert = 1$.

You have a direction vector in 3D, $\vec{d} = B - A = (3, 5, -6)$.  Project this to the visual plane using
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p} &= \vec{d} - \frac{\vec{d} \cdot \vec{w}}{\left\lVert \vec{w} \right\rVert} \vec{w} \\
~ &= \vec{d} - (\vec{d} \cdot \vec{w}) \vec{w} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Then, the dot products between the projected direction vector with the "right" and "up" vectors give you the direction cosines,
$$\begin{aligned}
x_\Delta &= \vec{p} \cdot \vec{u} \\
y_\Delta &= \vec{p} \cdot \vec{v} \\
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}\left(y_\Delta, x_\Delta\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\theta$ is the direction in 2D: $0°$ and $\pm 360°$ right, $+90°$ and $-270°$ up, $\pm 180°$ left, and $+270°$ and $-90°$ down, and $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ is the two-parameter form of $\arctan(y/x)$, except covering all angles by taking both signs into account.  Most programming languages provide this two-parameter form.

Because $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are perpendicular to $\vec{w}$, $x_\Delta$ and $y_\Delta$ are unchanged by projecting the direction vector to the viewing plane.  Thus, we can simplify the calculation to the following:

Let $\vec{u} = ( x_u , y_u , z_u )$ be the 3D vector that is directly right in the 2D view, and $\vec{v} = ( x_v , y_v , z_v )$ be the 3D vector that is directly up in the 2D view, and $\vec{d} = ( x_d , y_d , z_d ) = B - A$ the 3D direction vector.  Then,
$$\begin{aligned}
x_\Delta &= \vec{d} \cdot \vec{u} \\
y_\Delta &= \vec{d} \cdot \vec{v} \\
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}\left( y_\Delta , x_\Delta \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
or, in Cartesian coordinates,
$$\theta = \operatorname{atan2}\left( x_d x_v + y_d y_v + z_d z_v , \; x_d x_u + y_d y_u + z_d z_u \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining in such a simple way for a programmer like me. I'm so glad you managed to understand what I was trying to find out (I was thinking hard how I could rephrase the question). I managed to follow most concepts mentioned. I tried to simulate in a cube shape room, with real object that formed a straight line. The result calculated using the long method seems to give me an angle that look similar to the photo, whereas the simplified formula doesn't seem to work. I'll do more simulations programmatically and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jal: If $\vec{u} \perp \vec{w}$, then $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{p} = \vec{u} \cdot (\vec{p} + \lambda \vec{w})$ for any real $\lambda$, because $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{w} = 0$.  So, the problem can only be if the three vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$ are not all perpendicular to each other. You can use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthogonalize $\vec{u}$ against $\vec{w}$, then normalize it to unit length; then $\vec{v} = \vec{w} \times \vec{u}$.  If you like, I can show how to do that explicitly.

Comment: I tried implementing in my application, and I think I'm having problem finding the $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. I did some reading on rotations and quaternion, but it seems to me to these are rotating around the 3D space's x, y and z axes, instead of the viewing plane's x, y and z. Finding $\vec{u}$ is basically rotating around the $\vec{v}$ vector, and vice versa, as far as I could see. I'm currently trying to find one of the two unit vectors with roll, pitch and yaw, but I hadn't been successful so far. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.